# Python invalid syntax inputs

Tags: python

I'm having problems with a code I've been writing for about an hour or two, it was working and I was near to completing the game I was making, when it decided that I've done it wrong. I don't understand, I didn't edit this little bit of text, yet now, it has decided that it's wrong after having worked fine earlier! I'm a newbie to Python, but it's almost as if the text has changed it's mind about whether it wants to work or now.

```
room2 = input("> ")
if room2 == "2":
```

Okay so basically the code that I was doing was:

```
room = input ("> ")
if room = "1":
  print("blahblah")
```

What I'm going for is a text adventure.

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: which version of python are you using?

Comment: Invalid syntax, this is for pretty much every part of that same code.

Comment: Turn on the 'show white-space' feature of your editor and see if there is any inconsistent indentation.

Comment: I am using python 3.3.2

Comment: can you please post the full stacktrace of the error + the surrounding code lines it's referring to?

Comment: And more codes would help.

Comment: How do I do that? @greatwolf

Comment: Just run your script in question. It's suppose to print the error you're talking about in a form of a stack trace containing all the relevant function calls + which lines in your script it happened on. Copy and paste that verbatim into your question.

Comment: don't put it in a comment. edit your question with that information.

Comment: You are missing another `=` in this line: `if room = "1":`, it should be `if room == "1":` (like the `room2` line).

Comment: Oh yeah sorry my bad, I just wrote that, that wasn't in the script. I've double checked over it all and they've all got double '='. And I'm really sorry greatwolf, I'm an idiot, but what's question?

Comment: To save trouble, just paste in the whole code from your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you've forgotten a single `=` here. Remember that `=` is assignment and `==` the equality check in many languages.

```
if room == "1":
  print("blahblah")
```

Don't beat yourself up about it though, it happens. Just learn to check again.

Answer (score 2):

```
room = input ("> ")
if room == "1":  # You forgot one =
  print("blahblah")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
room = input ("> ")
if room == "1":
  print("blahblah")
```

= -> ==